# Django file upload - fileno Error

Tags: python, django, file-upload, urllib2

I am trying to upload a file (audio-file) from a django webapp to a django rest service.

The form:

```
<form method="post" action="/" name="submit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name="uploaded_file"><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The view:

```
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers
from poster.encode import multipart_encode
import urllib2

<...>

def post(self, request):
    """
    POST request: handles file upload to web service
    """
    uploaded_file = request.FILES['uploaded_file']

    server = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
    headers = {}

    # Register the streaming http handlers with urllib2
    register_openers()

    data = {
        'uploaded_file' : uploaded_file,
        'file_name' : uploaded_file.name,
        'additionalattr': 111,
    }

    datagen, headers = multipart_encode(data)
    headers['Authorization'] = 'Token <...>'

    headers['Connection']='keep-alive'
    urllib_request = urllib2.Request('%s/file_upload/' % ( server ), datagen, headers)

    json_response = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(urllib_request).read())

    return <...>
```

When I upload I file, I get following error code caused by multipart_encode:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/phoebus/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/phoebus/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 186, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/phoebus/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 184, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/phoebus/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/phoebus/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/phoebus/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/phoebus/Projects/speechanalyzerwebapp/speechanalyzerwebapp/welcome.py", line 41, in post
    datagen, headers = multipart_encode(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/poster/encode.py", line 411, in multipart_encode
    headers = get_headers(params, boundary)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/poster/encode.py", line 311, in get_headers
    headers['Content-Length'] = str(get_body_size(params, boundary))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/poster/encode.py", line 302, in get_body_size
    size = sum(p.get_size(boundary) for p in MultipartParam.from_params(params))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/poster/encode.py", line 177, in from_params
    filetype=filetype, fileobj=value))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/poster/encode.py", line 108, in __init__
    self.filesize = os.fstat(fileobj.fileno()).st_size
UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

Can anybody help me to understand what's going wrong and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: from where you are running django server, from commandline or any ide ?

Comment: no, both running from Terminal

Comment: seems like you are using unmaintained `poster` library,  its last update is 2009

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `UploadedFile` was not the problem, `poster` library you are using is older update Check latest version [here](https://bitbucket.org/chrisatlee/poster), updated my old answer

Comment: I just tried it, unfortunately the error still occurs. Thank you for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I had the same problem as you. I spent a long time and finally solved this problem.

Here my codes:

```py
import urllib2
from poster.encode import multipart_encode, MultipartParam
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers

register_openers()

class MyView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        uploaded_file = request.FILES.get('img', None)
        if uploaded_file:
            new_data = {}
            new_data['img'] = MultipartParam(
                'img',
                filename=uploaded_file.name,
                filetype=uploaded_file.content_type,         
                filesize=uploaded_file._size, # required, if missed, will raise `UnsupportedOperation: fileno` error
                fileobj=uploaded_file.file
            )
            datagen, headers = multipart_encode(new_data)
            request = urllib2.Request(URL, datagen, headers)
            response = urllib2.open(request)
            if response.code==200:
                print(response.read())
                return 'OK'
            else:
                return 'error'
```

Hope not too late and help for you.

Comment: I was inspired from [here](https://github.com/upyun/python-sdk/issues/11). If you are interested, maybe take a look.....